# Writing Raster Calculator Map Algebra expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I have the following map algebra expression to be used in Raster Calculator.

The "Output raster" should satisfy the following conditions:

```
If (IsUseAWSSites == True):
  if (InputRaster exists):
    Use "%InputRaster%" pixel value
  else:
    Use "%AnotherRaster%" pixel value
else:
  Use "%AnotherRaster%" pixel value
```

IsUseAWSSites is a boolean model param as variable.

InputRaster and AnotherRaster are Raster Dataset.

How do I turn this into a Con expression?